# Append to current div element in a while loop only

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

Good day everyone,

I have the following code structure. This code structure loads a page with different post subject and content on it. For each loaded post, a user can leave a comment. Have a look at the following code:

```
 <?php
      $getposts = "SELECT * FROM posts";
      if ($result = $con->query($getposts)) {
         while ($row1 = $result->fetch_assoc()) {

         $id = $row1['id'];
         $subject = $row1['sub'];
         $content = $row1['body'];
         $comments = $row1['comments'];

         echo"
           <div class='content_wrap'>
             <div class='subject'>$subject</div>
             <div class='content'>$content</div>
             <div class='comment'>$comments</div>
           </div>
         ";
    ?>
   <form id='reply' autocomplete="off">
     <input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $id;?>" name="id" id="pid"/>
     <input type="text" name="comment" id="comment" placeholder="Type a commmment here..."></input> 
   </form>

  <?php
   }
  }
 ?>

 <script type="text/javascript">
  $('form').submit(function () {
          var comment = $(this).find('input[name=comment]').val();
          var id = $(this).find('input[name=id]').val();
          $.post("comments_ins.php", { pub_id: id, comment: comment});                              
          $(this).parent().children('.content_wrap').append("<div 
          class='comment'" + comment + "</div");                                   
          var comment = $(this).find('input[name=comment]').val('');
          return false;
        });
    </script>
```

All of the above codes I currently have in one page...and the file is a php file type.

Notice that there is a form generated for each loaded post on the page according to the while loop. 
The code above works about 90 percent correct. But one thing I don't seem to get right. 
I want that when a user leaves a comment, that the comment displays on the page for that post only....nut all of the loaded posts on the page. 
So, if a user types a first comment, it is visible, and, if the user types another comment on to that same post, the new comment falls under the previous comment posted....and is visible ....so that it appends to a div element each time a user types a comment.

How do I go about accomplishing this?

If you look at my javascript above, I made an attempt but it did not work for me.

Guidance would be appreciated. 
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

try appending an ID to your divs so you can locate them more easily

```
         $id = $row1['id'];
         $subject = $row1['sub'];
         $content = $row1['body'];
         $comments = $row1['comments'];

         echo"
           <div class='content_wrap'>
             <div class='subject' id=subject_$id>$subject</div>
             <div class='content' id=content_$id>$content</div>
             <div class='comment' id=comment_$id>$comments</div>
           </div>
         ";
```

This should let you append to only the div you want it on.

Comment: Hey Trevor, Thanks for the reply. But, how do I now set up the javascript part to now work with your new configuration? I did what you said to the php part already...I am still not very good at these stuff so any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I am not 100% sure I follow what your goal is but I think you just need to narrow down your jquery selector.  Now you can search by id instead of by class, which would be returning every comment box.
Do you have the page running somewhere that we could look at and see all the code?

Comment: I don't have a live page but this is exact coding. I tried this line in the javacript tags:  $(".comment_body_$postid").append("Test");   but that can't work. The php works well with the new id configuration but is to find a way to make the java piece capture each postid from the php while loop specified for each post and have it assigned to that div only that format the posts. But i am stock here main while

Comment: You can select any of the elements like this.
$("#comment_<?= $id ?>").text("test");
Assuming $id is your php variable with the ID number.  Replace with the correct variable if needed